# Opamp as latching comparator

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, logic-gates, comparator, latch

So I have one unused OpAmp left in my circuit and I would like to use it as "latching comparator" (for lack of a better name), but I'm having hard time wrapping my head around it. Here is how I want it to behave:
[image: "latching comparator" behaviour]

Desired properties are:

- Fairly high input impedance
- Works without inputs reaching rail volatges
- Speed doesn't matter.

Closest thing that I found so far is 
[this](http://m.eet.com/media/1159278/297458-use_an_op_amp_as_a_set_reset_flip_flop_figure_1.jpg). But I wasn't able to figure out how can adapt it to my application.

I hope this makes some sense. I'm trying to keep it abstract(quick to read), but if more detail is needed or this turns out not to be possible - I'll add in more info.

---

Ok, so to be more precise of what my goal is:

I'm using LM3419 as bar-graph driver chip and I need a circuit that would latch when top graph LED turns on and stay untill bottom LED turns off.
I use output of that to enable/disable some other chips.

LM3914 pulls constant current through LEDs, but I don't know what LEDs at what current I will use, hence arbitrary "high" and "low" levels.
I have one free LM358 available and I wonder if I can make it work as described.

Wanted to add schematic representation here, but it doesn't let me (need more reputation). I hope it's understandable :P

Comment: It seems you need just a hysteresis configuration.

Comment: Google Schmidt trigger

Answer (score 1):

Try this; given the circuit will latch, with +-0.5 volt overdrive to provide robust 1-bit-storage, are diodes from your Set and Reset inputs all you need to add?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foD0LV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Although the circuit is sound I would use 10x or even 100x smaller resistor values. With these 10 Mohm and higher resistors 1) the voltage drops as soon as you connect a multimeter (which will be 10 M ohm input impedance) and 2) the circuit will be disturbed when you sneeze at close range. I'd use 100 kohm and 220 kohm instead and enjoy a less sensitive circuit.

Comment: Yes. The OP needs to provide the real specs required, eh?

Comment: I've just tried it in breadboard with 100x smaller resistors and it doesn't seem to work (when input2 goes high, output falls back down).

Comment: My input "high" sits at 2.8V and "low" is 1.6V, I guess it will become more clear if I append what it is that I'm trying to do.

Comment: What opamp are you using ? The suggested TL081 is **unsuitable** for 5 V. You could increase the supply to 15 V and see if that works or use an opamp more suitable for a 5 V supply.

Comment: Yea I haven't checked if that one can go to negative rail, I am using LM358 and 5V is the only regulated supply I have.

Comment: The [LM358](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf) is designed to be powered from + and - 1.5v at minimum, and is not a "rail-to-rail" op-amp. So powering it from +5 and 0v might give a minimum output of 0.8v, and a maximum of 4.2v. Some digital chips might not interpret this output as "digital" at all. Some digging with a fine-toothed comb is in order. :)